# using find my phone to "track" kid does it send email or other notice to kid?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

my son is overseas and I had to send him a new phone...before sending I turned on location services so that I could log onto find my phone on my phone and locate his phone.  (his first phone was stolen so thought would be good to have)
He is now saying that he keeps getting emails saying I am using Find my phone to find his phone...I have never heard that it sends an email to the person?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "find my iphone" use the "find friends" app. It's from Apple and I use it all the time.

I saw that the OP was using the wrong tool for the job. “Find my phone” does send notices as a feature. Of course if the OP wants to find a lost or stolen phone it’s the right tool and the emails wouldn’t be an issue.

If the user wants to “track” the other user, however, then “Find Friends” is the correct tool to use

Comment: Sorry if I answered wrongly, I was trying to be helpful.  I saw that the OP was using the wrong tool for the job. “Find my phone” does send notices as a feature. Of course if the OP wants to find a lost or stolen phone it’s the right tool and the emails wouldn’t be an issue. If the user wants to “track” the other user, however, then “Find Friends” is the correct tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud will send emails to the registered email address if any event is triggered on Find My iPhone (including logging in to iCloud)